# C# Windows service needs to make registry changes

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I have a service that needs to update the registry every 5 minutes (counteract GPO). The code runs fine in a regular application, but when I put it in a windows service, it doesn't make the changes. I am using the local system account for the service and it is not throwing any exceptions

The code below works in a regular console app but not in the service:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
if (key != null)
{
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaverIsSecure", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaveActive", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaveTimeOut", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("SCRNSAVE.EXE", "", RegistryValueKind.String);
}


key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop", true);
if (key != null)
{
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaverIsSecure", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaveActive", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("ScreenSaveTimeOut", "0", RegistryValueKind.String);
    key.SetValue("SCRNSAVE.EXE", "", RegistryValueKind.String);
}
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE", "user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters");
```

Any Ideas?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the replies.  I don't know why the **"CurrentUser"** escaped my attention. Thanks for pointing that out.

My problem still remains that the group policy is being pushed against the **CurrentUser**. Right now I am considering just creating an app that loads at startup and stays active.  Any other suggestions would be welcome.

**EDIT:**

As to Will's comment, I am unable to find the `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` function signature in the win32 API. Does that imply that it can be called without parameters?

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool UpdatePerUserSystemParameters();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> A service that runs in the context of the LocalSystem account inherits the security context of the SCM...This has several implications:
>
> The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is associated with the default user, not the current user. To access another user's profile, impersonate the user, then access HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Answer (score 3):

What (who) do you expect `Currentuser` to be inside a service?

Answer (score 2):

Registry is always fun, but doesn't that mean that you are editing the **user** registry settings of the "local system" user? So unless your *actual* user is logged in as "local system" (which I seriously doubt), they aren't going to see anything...

I suspect you need to edit the machine-wide settings, or the *active* user(s).

Answer (score 2):

Run your service under another account that actually has a login.

The Local System account isn't a user, and therefore there is no Registry.CurrentUser key (no login = no current user = no current user key.

Comment: Actually, Local System/Local Service/Network Service account got their  HKCU entries. Just check HK_USERS.

Answer (score 2):

If it works outside of the service, it may be a permissions issue. Are you getting an exception when you try to use key.SetValue()? Is the service running under an account that has write access to the registry?

Answer (score 1):

try putting the registry manipulation code in a try-catch block; services run in secondary threads, which eat exceptions